# C++03 Resolve a circle composition when calling a member function

Tags: c++, composition, member-functions

I've got the following class structure. This obviously won't compile. I can forward declare B. Then, I can either use function pointers in function calls but it's not a nice solution, as I would call other other functions in A from A::funcA or put part of the declaration of B into a header, which would be a few hundreds of lines and would be practical.

What (else) would be the preferred way to handle this situation?

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    void funcA(B* b);
    double funcA2();
    int funcA4(B* b);

private:
    E memberA1;
    E memberA2;
};

void A::funcA( B* b) {
    b->funcB(a->memberA1, a->memberA2);

class B : public BBase
{
public:
    void FuncB(E* e1, E* e2)
    {
        /* using const objects of B that are initialized 
           by B() and some other functions... */
    }

    std::vector<C*> memberB1;             // C has std::vector<A*> memberC1
};

int main() {
    calling B->memberB1.at(0)->memberC1.at(0)->funcA();
}
```

I have the the following (omitting some unneccesary lines):

**A.h**

```
Class B;

Class A {
    declaration of A
};
```

**A.cpp** ....

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "BBase.h"

Class B {
    declaration of B
};
```

**B.cpp** ....

**BBase.h**

```
#include "C.h"
#include "A.h"
#include "AInterface.h"

typedef std::vector<AInterface> AList;

BBase {
   declaration of abstract BBase
};
```

**BBase.cpp** ....`

But I still get error: member access into incomplete type 'B'.

Comment: You *do* include `"B.h"` in `BBase.cpp`?

Comment: No, in the `cpp`-s only the corresponding `.h` is included. e.g. `BBase.cpp` has `BBase.h` only.

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? If you use `B` you need the full definition of the `B` class, and so need to include the `B.h` file in that source file.

Comment: I get it in `A.cpp` while trying to use `B->funcB(...);`
If I include `B.h` in `A.h`, then I get 
`expected class name` in `B.h` and `unknown typename A` and `unknown typename Alist` in `B.h`.

Comment: Can you please create some *complete* code, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show us?

Comment: I've uploaded a [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/eX9afQjP). ( I hope I didn't miss something out)
Depending of including headers in the end of `a.h` or not I either get `incomplete type` or `undeclared identifier C`.

I know that this is obviously wrong. I just can't figure out a good way of solving it.

Many thanks for helping so far **Joachim**!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `E` and `C` are adequately declared/defined, then what you have is *almost* fine. The problem is that you define the member function of `A` before you have the definition of the `B` class, make sure that class `B` is fully defined (the actual class, not the full implementation of its member functions) before you you have the `A` member functions implemented.

So something like this:

```
class B;

class A { ...; void member_function(B*); ... };

class B { ...; void other_member_function(); ... };

void A::member_function(B* b) { ...; b->other_member_function(); ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use either the Interface instead of concrete B class

```
class B : public IB{
};
```

and pass IB instead of B to A.

either even better in c++ use a template function and bind your member function which you want to call

```
a.funcA( std::bind( &B::funcB, &b, someArg );
```

Comment: I cannot use C++11 unfortunately (bind).

Comment: you can use boost::bind instead.